# Todo / Note Taking app that is structured like a mind-map app

Tags: note-taking, productivity, todo

I found a site several months ago for a productivity tool that marketed itself as a different way of organizing your...todo stuff (or maybe notes?), using a graph-like interface--with nodes and edges--perhaps like a mind-map. There was a user quote on the site saying that it was an epiphany for them when they realized how well it worked to organize things in an "associative" fashion instead of in lists.

I don't remember if it was more of a notes system that might replace something like Evernote, or a todo list sytem that might replace something like Remember The Milk. (Or both).

I believe it's a relatively new app. But now I can't find it. Any idea what it was?

Answer (score 1):

Good that you found it.

Otherwise I might have thought of [TiddlyMap](http://tiddlymap.org/), which is free and open source.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I think that may be better for me actually. I like that they are a little more of a map, but with notes on all the nodes. (also that it is free :S)

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It's called [Roam](https://roamresearch.com/). It appears to be structured around inter-note associations, as opposed to inter-task associations. That's my first impression anyway.